# Visual Studio 2019 crashing when trying to open a winforms designer after installing new VS2022 preview

Tags: windows, crash, visual-studio-2019

I have downloaded the vs 2022 preview which after restart caused all my Winforms projects to just crash at trying to load the designer, This happens in the latest version of VS2019 I uninstalled vs2022 but the problem still persists.

> Debug Data:
>
> > VS 2019 Latest Version (Winforms Designer (.NET Framework 4.8), Windows Insider Preview DEV channel Home 64-Bit )

Edit:

I have found the problem, but can't solve it. The problem lies with the user controls, any attempt to place them on the form results in a crash.

Comment: Have you attempted to repair the Visual Studio 2019 installation?

Comment: Does this happen with a fresh winforms project or only ones that you have already created?  Figuring out what is crashing winforms is a PITA but you can do it by blocking out parts of the designer file.  And most/many times.. for me at least, the repair doesn't fix diddly squiddly.  I have had to uninstall/reinstall more times than I can count over the last 20+ years.  Note:  never install MS preview on your primary box.  Only VM.. previews often break stuff.

Comment: it happens with a project pre vs2022 install and no I have not attempted to repair I will now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked online for an answer, and it is possible that the controls on the form are broken due to the .sln files being updated. Try open the control itself. If it works I would suggest to make a new control, and then copy and paste the code to from the broken one and then the designer code. I please then remove all traces from the code/designer of the broken elements, then remove the old "broken" controls and rename the new ones to the previous name(s), and build.

Once the build is successful place the new controls back how they were and it should not crash.

Do this in other projects if you have any.